# Draw on a phylogeny edge with R

Tags: r, phylogeny

I want to draw a symbol (cross) anywhere along an edge of a phylogeny with R.

Let us take that tree:

tree.mod

```
(((((hg19:0.0295977,macFas5:0.0351997)hg19-macFas5:0.0796862,otoGar3:0.153768)hg19-otoGar3:0.0189364,(((speTri2:0.136745,(mm10:0.0836004,rn5:0.0894755)mm10-rn5:0.221692)speTri2-mm10:0.009583,cavPor3:0.230585)speTri2-cavPor3:0.0279417,oryCun2:0.212423)speTri2-oryCun2:0.0141334)hg19-speTri2:0.0224427,((susScr3:0.127502,(camFer1:0.111428((HLbalAcu1:0.0196864,(HLphyCat1:0.0216245,(HLlipVex1:0.0178214,(turTru2:0.00660779,orcOrc1:0.00557822)turTru2-orcOrc1:0.0113362)HLlipVex1-turTru2:0.00784223)HLphyCat1-HLlipVex1:0.00385294)HLbalAcu1-HLphyCat1:0.0417511(bosTau7:0.0320796,oviAri3:0.0370855)bosTau7-oviAri3:0.0963575)HLbalAcu1-bosTau7:0.0212413)camFer1-HLbalAcu1:0.00459573)susScr3-camFer1:0.0425276,((equCab2:0.107972,(felCat5:0.0893591,(canFam3:0.0908515,((ailMel1:0.0208923,HLursMar1:0.0194161)ailMel1-HLursMar1:0.041512,(odoRosDiv1:0.0259201,lepWed1:0.0238902)odoRosDiv1-lepWed1:0.0288135)ailMel1-odoRosDiv1:0.0213261)canFam3-ailMel1:0.0207311)felCat5-canFam3:0.0501969)equCab2-felCat5:0.00485202,myoLuc2:0.169981)equCab2-myoLuc2:0.00361502)susScr3-equCab2:0.0302374)hg19-susScr3:0.0217021,(((loxAfr3:0.0821245,triMan1:0.0662932)loxAfr3-triMan1:0.0296365,echTel2:0.245195)loxAfr3-echTel2:0.0492624,dasNov3:0.159632)loxAfr3-dasNov3:0.00825218)hg19-loxAfr3;
```

and plot it with a symbol at the hg19 tip:

```
R
library(ape)
tree = read.tree("tree.mod")
plot(tree)
points( 0.172365, 1, col="red", pch=20)
```

that is easy for the tips: the 'x' value is the full branch length, and 'y' is 1,2,3...

but I don't see how to do it for inner nodes like for instance loxAfr3-triMan1. I have the 'x' but cannot find the 'y'...

Any input welcome!

Comment: How are you plotting this? `plot(tree)` doesn't seems to work; it gives the error "there are single (non-splitting) nodes in your tree; you may need to use collapse.singles()". And you can't just call `points()` without plotting something first.

Comment: Some issue with copy&paste, please use that tree:   http://idisk-srv1.mpi-cbg.de/~prudent/tree.mod

Comment: So where exactly do you want the point? Can you create a mock-up in Paint or something to make it clear where you are trying to draw the point?

Comment: Please have a look at: http://idisk-srv1.mpi-cbg.de/~prudent/exampeTree.jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I feel like I must be missing an easier way, but much of those code seems to be tucked away inside C functions called by the package's plotting function. Nevertheless, here are some functions in R that should be able to extract the x and y positions for particular nodes.

```
getphylo_x <- function(tree, node) {
    if(is.character(node)) {
        node <- which(c(tree$tip.label, tree$node.label)==node)
    }
    pi <- tree$edge[tree$edge[,2]==node, 1]
    if (length(pi)) {
        ei<-which(tree$edge[,1]==pi & tree$edge[,2]==node)
        tree$edge.length[ei] + Recall(tree, pi)
    } else {
        if(!is.null(tree$root.edge)) {
            tree$root.edge
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}

getphylo_y <- function(tree, node) {
    if(is.character(node)) {
        node <- which(c(tree$tip.label, tree$node.label)==node)
    }
    ci <- tree$edge[tree$edge[,1]==node, 2]
    if (length(ci)==2) {
        mean(c(Recall(tree, ci[1]), Recall(tree, ci[2])))
    } else if (length(ci)==0) {
        Ntip <- length(tree$tip.label)
        which(tree$edge[tree$edge[, 2] <= Ntip, 2] == node)
    } else {
        stop(paste("error", length(ci)))
    }
}
```

To use them, you just pass in your tree and your node name. For example

```
node <- "loxAfr3-triMan1"
x <- getphylo_x(tree, node)
y <- getphylo_y(tree, node)


plot(tree)
points(x,y,pch=18, col="red", cex=2)
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Excellent! That works perfectly. I in fact just came with a solution too, but much more ugly $ long. Thanks a lot and greetings to Michigan from France!

Comment: I'm late to the party but it seems to me that `node.height()` and `node.depth.edgelength()` do what you want without the need to use custom functions.

Comment: @jeanlain I wasn't aware of those functions. If you would write up an answer that shows how to extract those values for a given node name, that would be helpful.

Comment: This is really awesome! Thanks for sharing the code! Any ideas how to do the same with circular phylogenies?

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Flick's answer seems to have this totally covered, but I thought I would add that the locator function while run with your tree plot open will allow you to get x,y coordinates of user specified points. Useful for things like x,y placement of a scale.

```html
plot(tree)
locator()
```

It will return the x and y coordinates for all the points clicked before hitting Esc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't require custom functions.

Given the tree linked by the OP in one of their comments:

```
tree <- read.tree()   #file name isn't specified so ape will read what you paste in the console
((A:0.2,(B:0.1,C:0.1):0.1):0.1,((E:0.1,F:0.1):0.1,D:0.2):0.1);


plot(tree)
#Some random internal node:
node <- sample(tree$Nnode, 1) + length(tree$tip.label)  #nodes are not named in this tree
#if you want a (named) tip:
tip <- which(tree$tip.label == "A")
points(node.depth.edgelength(tree)[c(node, tip)], node.height(tree)[c(node,tip)], pch=18, col="red", cex=2)
```